# How to use `whereDoesntHave` in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to fetch users who don't have productions by checking the start date and end date ranges.

```
 $production = Production::find($id);

$users = User::whereDoesntHave('productions', function ($query) {
    return $query
        ->where(function ($q) {
            return $q->whereBetween('start_at', [$production->start_at, $production->end_at])
                ->whereBetween('end_at', [$production->start_at, $production->end_at]);
        });
})->get();

//User Production relation
public function productions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Production::class)
        ->withPivot(['created_at', 'updated_at']);
}
```

This returns users who are already assigned in other productions within current production start date and end date that and I only want to fetch users who has no production assignment within the current date range.

Comment: We need more info to help you precisely. Can you give a simple data schema with the relations between user and production tables ? Also show how are the relationship declared in your eloquent models ?

Comment: Where does the  $production variable come from? As it is, it would throw an exception

Comment: Even with the edit, there is still unclear things: Where does the `$production` var come from ? What is the purpose of `use ($startDate, $endDate)` if you never use those variables ? What exactly are you trying to get based on the variables names ? ex: "I want a list of users that have no productions which start dates are between $startDate and $endDate " ?

Comment: With that change, you now need `use ($production)` on both of your `function ($query)` and `function ($q)` calls. You need to pass `$production` forward via that `use()` statement, otherwise it will not be available where you're attempting to use it.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I have edited for this context.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a Production model instance in the `$production` variable. You want all users that doesn't have production that overlap with the time range of the `$production` instance ?

**Your current code** (pasted from your question):

```
$production = Production::find($id);

$users = User::whereDoesntHave('productions', function ($query) {
    return $query
        ->where(function ($q) {
            return $q->whereBetween('start_at', [$production->start_at, $production->end_at])
                ->whereBetween('end_at', [$production->start_at, $production->end_at]);
        });
})->get();
```

**What you should do** :

```
$production = Production::find($id);

$users = User::whereDoesntHave('productions', function ($query) use($production) {
        return $query->whereBetween('start_at', [$production->start_at, $production->end_at])
                ->orWhereBetween('end_at', [$production->start_at, $production->end_at]);
    });
})->get();
```

I think the key thing here is include both start and end range in the result vith a `orWhereBetween` condition instead of `whereBetween`.  And don't forget to use the `$production` variable in the closure ;-)

If this is not what you are trying to do, please comment to explain more precisely what you want to do

Comment: I have to check also the start_at and end date of the production because I am avoiding to assign user in production where there is dates interference.

Comment: I think I edited to match your use case. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the dates as parameters but you never actually use them,
this is how it should be:

```
$users = User::whereDoesntHave('productions', function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
        return $query->where(function ($q) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                return $q->whereBetween('start_at', [$startDate,$endDate])
                    ->orWhereBetween('end_at', [$startDate, $endDate]);
            });
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: I have edited my questions and I have removed closure function parameters